# How to convert Ubuntu Desktop into Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 14.04, server

I am having my machine installed with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop version. but now I need Ubuntu server edition. can I integrate both or else should I replace my desktop version with server edition . please help me

Answer (score 1):

There is not much difference between Desktop & Server. Check this link. You dont need to replace your desktop rather install servers like apache,etc

Execute this command in terminal to make your desktop Ubuntu server :

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 phpmyadmin lamp-server^ mail-server^ openssh-server^
```